# What is the difference between resolvent kernel and iterative kernel of an integral equation?

Tags: integral-transforms, integral-equations

As we have different methods to find resolvent kernel, which is more suitable among all those methods? And what is the difference between resolvent and iterative kernels?

Comment: Suppose $K(x,t)=K_{1}(x,t)$ is your 1st kernel then $K_{2}(x,t)=\int\limits_{t}^{x} k(x,z) \cdot K_{1}(z,t) \ dz$. This $K_{2}(x,t)$ is called as the iterated kernel. Whereas Resolvent Kernel $R$ is defined as $R(x,t) = \sum_{i} K_{i}(x,t)$.

Comment: Please proof-read your question once before posting it. Your post had a slew of spelling mistakes [that could be easily avoided].

Answer (score 1):

CW answer to remove it from unanswered queue:

Suppose $K(x,t)=K_1(x,t)$ is your $1^{st}$ kernel, then $K_2(x,t)=\int\limits_t^x K(x,z)⋅K_1(z,t)dz$. This $K_2(x,t)$ is called as the iterated kernel. In general, we have $K_n(x,t)=\int\limits_t^x K(x,z)⋅K_{n-1}(z,t)dz$.

Whereas Resolvent Kernel $R$ is defined as $R(x,t)=\sum_i\lambda^{i-1} K_i(x,t)$.